# AS3 load bitmapData from JPG/PNG bytearray synchronously

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, png, jpeg

Given a ByteArray containing JPG or PNG data, is there a way to retrieve synchronically a corresponding BitmapData in Adobe AIR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JPEGDecoder](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1089)

[PNGDecoder](http://code.google.com/p/katopz/source/browse/branches/as3/cutecoma/src/PNGDecoder.as?r=174)

Otherwise, use loadBytes.  I'd say use loadBytes, since it won't halt your thread.